# next() call not iterating

Tags: python, iterator

```
var = 10
Constant = 10
def Gen():
    i = 1
    for x in range(var):
        yield i
        i +=1   
o = Gen()

c = next(o) * Constant

for i in range(var):
    print(c)
```

What I've tried and their errors:

```
c = {next(o)} * Constant
        #unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'set' and 'int'
c = int({next(o)}) * Constant
        #int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'set'`
```

Expected output:

```
10
20
30
40 
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `next()` you are asking for just one value. Since you want to iterate on the values returned by your generator you may write a loop, or a set comprehension, for instance:

```
c = {z * Constant for z in o}
```

The syntax you used just got a single value, put it in a `set`, and tried to multiply the `set` by `Constant`.

Side note: why a `set` and not a `list`?

Comment: How to get around: a print statement expends the generator before moving onto next print statement